# How to have `lftp` compare directories and only sync changed files?

Tags: linux, debian, sync, ftps, lftp

The entirety of my question is summed up in the title.

If there isn't a way to do this, what FTPS-compatible alternative would allow it?

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 11 (Bullseye) Stable.

Answer (score 1):

The `lftp` has `mirror` command to synchronize local nd remote folders:

```
mirror [OPTS] [source [target]]
```

You didn't specify in what direction you want to synchronize. The `mirror` by default synchronizes remote to local. To reverse the direction, add `-R` switch.

See https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html